# X configuration resets on display change

Tags: ubuntu, x11, i3

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, but I use i3 as my window manager. I've set up `~/.xprofile` to configure my key repeat rate, and some custom keyboard mappings (see below)

```
# Detect and apply current monitor layout
autorandr --change 2>/dev/null

# Set key repeat rate
xset r rate 200 40

# Set wallpaper
set-random-wallpaper

# Set up caps to be:
# - <esc> when tapped
# - <ctrl> when held
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape' &
```

(`set-random-wallpaper` is a minimal script I wrote to set my desktop background -- it runs as a cron job, but is called here to set the initial background on login)

I use [`autorandr`](https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr) to manage my monitor configuration -- this is a laptop, and I often transition between 'docked' and 'roaming' configurations which require different monitor setup.

My problem is this: Every time I enter or leave the docked state, my keyboard mappings and key repeat rate is reset to Ubuntu's default. My hunch is that I'm fighting with a different configuration system, but I haven't been able to find where that is.

Am I going about my configuration in the wrong way? Is there indeed an underlying Ubuntu system that hasn't been properly disabled?

I know it looks like I have a serious case of Arch envy (and I do!), but this is a work machine, and most of our SOPs are built assuming a Ubuntu OS, especially with `apt`...

Comment: I suspect that something is listening to D-Bus notifications. You can monitor them with `dbus-monitor`. I don't know how to find who is listening to a particular notification but checking the processes that are connected to the D-Bus socket would be a start.

Comment: Two questions come to mind: 1. Does this also happen when (un)docking, if you do not use `autorandr` (including the udev rule)? 2. Does it happen, if you manually run the `xrandr` command independent from the docking process?

Comment: Thanks @Adaephon ! Those were some useful troubleshooting steps.. 1. It does still happen without `autorandr`. 2. It doesn't happen manually changing monitor config with `xrandr`. I also discovered that the problem isn't associated with any docking/undocking transition, but only with going from the undocked -> docked state. Furthermore, the problem corrects itself if I undock again, even if I don't re-execute `~/.xprofile`. I'm going to dig through the installed udev rules and see where that gets me.

Comment: I have the same issue on Linux mint. Were you ever able to find the solution for this?